# Does atomic_cmpxchg() imply memory barriers?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, synchronization, atomic, compare-and-swap

The following two citations seem contradicting:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt

> int atomic_cmpxchg(atomic_t *v, int old, int new);
>
> This performs an atomic compare exchange operation on the atomic value
>   v, with the given old and new values. Like all atomic_xxx operations,
>   atomic_cmpxchg will only satisfy its atomicity semantics as long as
>   all other accesses of *v are performed through atomic_xxx operations.
>
> atomic_cmpxchg requires explicit memory barriers around the operation.

vs

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

> Any atomic operation that modifies some state in memory and returns
>   information about the state (old or new) implies an SMP-conditional
>   general memory barrier (smp_mb()) on each side of the actual operation
>   (with the exception of explicit lock operations, described later). 
>   These include:
>
> ```
>       <...>   
>       atomic_xchg();  
>       atomic_cmpxchg();
>       <...>
> ```
>
> These are used for such things as implementing LOCK-class and UNLOCK-class operations and adjusting reference
>   counters towards object destruction, and as such the implicit memory
>   barrier effects are necessary.

So should one put memory barriers around `atomic_xchg()` manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware yet about Linux kernel programming specifics, so here is a partial (general) answer.

On x86, this operation carries full memory fence with it, there is no need in `mfence`/`lfence`/`sfence` around `cmpxchg` op.

On other architectures with relaxed memory model, it can be coupled with other memory semantics, e.g. "release", depending on how `atomic_cmpxchg()` is translated to the op codes.

It's on the processor side of things. However, there is compiler which can also reorder the operations, so if compiler barrier is not implied by `atomic_cmpxchg()` (by e.g. `__asm__ __volatile__`), you would need one.